# How do I make a block only be placed on a certain block when crafted?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map but I'm stuck on a command
When a player crafts an item I want to let it only be placed on a block, like when a player crafts a crafting table, the command block will make so it's only placeable on gravel. I seen it in other maps.
How do I do it?
Also I want to make it so certain tools and break some blocks
If anyone knows please tell me.
P.S. not the /give command

Comment: have you heard of `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` yet?

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted to make a diamond block to be able to placed on a diamond ore (for example), you must use this command in a command block or in chat:

```
/give @p diamond_block 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]}
```

Very complicated, I know, but the `CanPlaceOn:["(yourblock)"]` is the block you want it to be placed on, and the `/give @p (Yourotherblock)` is the block you will be placing it on.

Comment: A quote from the question "P.S. not the /give command"  The OP does not want this answer.